# Can I change the contents of a description meta tag generated by Yoast in a WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, yoast

I am quite new to WordPress so I am not sure how this would work.

Essentially I have the Yoast plugin handling my SEO related things. The main one giving problems is the description meta tag.

The site is bilingual and I would like the description meta tag to be translated as well. Yoast currently does not provide that option, unless I get another plugin which I do not want to get into.

As it stands, I am told that I can insert the description meta tag through the `functions.php` using `add_action`. This unfortunately does not work as it only adds another description meta tag.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
function insert_meta_tag_in_head () {
    echo '<meta name="description" content="My New content" />';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'insert_meta_tag_in_head', 1);
```

So basically this just gives me a second description meta tag. I have also seen in other threads, that if I want to replace a tag, I should use the `do_action` function. Which I call as follows:

```
do_action('wp_head', 'insert_meta_tag_in_head');
```

This however does nothing.
What am I doing wrong? How can I change the contents of the description tag given to me through Yoast?

Comment: Are you using WPML to make the site multilingual?

Comment: Nope. From what I gathered, it is payed for, no? So I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've previously [changed a Yoast title before](https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/change-yoast-seo-meta-title-with-_get-superglobal-url-parameter/), however, a [description](https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-change-the-yoast-seo-description-through-the-functions-file/) is something we have been working on too.

To sum-up the link above:

> You need to filter the `wpseo_metadesc` action in order to display your
>   new description.

```
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc', 'new_desc_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_wpseo_title');
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc', 'filter_wpseo_metadesc');
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_title', 'filter_wpseo_opengraph_title');
add_filter('wpseo_twitter_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_twitter_title');
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_url', 'filter_product_wpseo_opengraph_url');
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_desc', 'filter_product_wpseo_opengraph_desc');
add_filter('wpseo_twitter_image', 'filter_product_wpseo_tweeter_image');
```

**these all are the filter which can be use to replacement Yoast SEO Premium plugin opengraphs**

*wpseo_title ,
wpseo_metadesc,
wpseo_opengraph_title,
wpseo_twitter_title,
wpseo_opengraph_url,
wpseo_opengraph_desc,
wpseo_twitter_image*